# Selection of module for person following shopping cart

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi

I'm building a person following shopping cart with Arduino for my final year project. The cart is supposed to be able to follow its user while shopping use of Bluetooth module or wifi module will be feasible or not?or I should use IR sensors ?

Comment: It seems like this is a big/complicated project. Probably you need a multitude of modules (like WIFI or BlueTooth for the communication between the person and the cart, not sure what is best), an IR sensors to make sure the cart is not hitting something, and since safety is an issue (not bumping into people) you might need also probably one or more cameras, with vision intelligence, making an Arduino Uno not the best choice. But maybe I'm too pessimistic.

Comment: I agree with @MichelKeijzers ... perhaps the shopper could wear a vest with IR emitters ... each vest would transmit a unique code ..

Comment: @jsotola that could work, although much depends on the way the person with the vest walks (not too fast, not abrupt changes of direction/turning).

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth beacon. Use "bluetooth positioning arduino" as search terms.

Bluetooth beacon is a way to achieve the same as a GPS can do outdoor. By placing beacons around the room you can find your position in 3D space.

So a beacon locator on the shopping cart (Arduino with BLE module or a ESP32) and one on you (mobile phone) and then some central unit that can coordinate the two positions.

Just as a concept it would be feasible.